# TeX style manual

Tags: discussion

Is there some sort of TeX style manual that most posters to stackexchange use?  Where is it?  (That so many share some of the same details of style make me suspect this.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please

Comment: Could you mention some of these details? I haven't noticed this.

Comment: **Style** manual? I am not entirely sure I understand your question. But assuming that I read you correctly, note that [this tool](http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) has been passed around here on Meta every now and then, which may explain why sometimes the LaTeX codes used by new users look similar.

Comment: One simple thing is things like \int_{0}^{1} instead of \int_0^1.  A more elaborate example that I've seen several times, including once in the past couple of days, is things like {{a}_{b}} instead of a_b.

Comment: @WillieWong : It does appear that the thing you linked to would explain at least some of what I have in mind.